# 3d Wall sliding collision

Tags: c#, 3d, xna, collision

I'm working on collision for walls in my game and the way I currently have it I get stuck walking into a wall. I'm trying to make my character slide on the walls but still collide.

My character moves off of a vector I create using the angle he is facing.

this is my collision function:

```
    private static bool CheckForCollisions(ref Crate c1, ref Player c2,bool direction)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < c1.model.Meshes.Count; i++)
        {
            // Check whether the bounding boxes of the two cubes intersect.
            BoundingSphere c1BoundingSphere = c1.model.Meshes[i].BoundingSphere;
            c1BoundingSphere.Center += c1.position + new Vector3(2, 0, 2);
            c1BoundingSphere.Radius = c1BoundingSphere.Radius / 1.5f;

            for (int j = 0; j < c2.model.Meshes.Count; j++)
            {
                BoundingSphere c2BoundingSphere = c2.model.Meshes[j].BoundingSphere;
                if (direction)
                    c2BoundingSphere.Center += c2.position + new Vector3(c2.getPlannedDirection().X, 0, 0);
                else if (!direction)
                    c2BoundingSphere.Center += c2.position + new Vector3(0, 0, c2.getPlannedDirection().Y);
                //c2BoundingSphere.Center += c2.position;

                if (c1BoundingSphere.Intersects(c2BoundingSphere))
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

This is my update:

```
for (int x = 0; x <= 29; x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y <= 29; y++)
            {
                if (crate[x, y].getType() == 11 && collisionEnabled)
                { 
                    if (CheckForCollisions(ref crate[x, y], ref player,true))
                    {
                        player.clearPlannedDirectionX();
                        //Console.Write(player.getPosition().X + "," + player.getPosition().Y + "," + player.getPosition().Z);
                        //movePlayer = false;
                    }
                    if (CheckForCollisions(ref crate[x, y], ref player,false))
                    {
                        player.clearPlannedDirectionZ();
                        //Console.Write(player.getPosition().X + "," + player.getPosition().Y + "," + player.getPosition().Z);
                        //movePlayer = false;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: you're using getPlannedDirection().X and getPlannedDirection().Y in the first code but you're using clearPlannedDirectionX() and clearPlannedDirectionZ() in the second

Comment: Yeah what it was doing was if it would collide on the z axis then it stops it from happening. same with the x axis. this is all run before the player updates its position. that's why its called "PlannedDirection", sorry i should have clarified that in my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like it should be on gamedev stack exchange, and I would recommend switching to ray tests instead of sphere.

Anyways, If you are married to your sphere-based system, you could "push" players out of the walls instead:

```
private static bool CorrectCollisions(ref Crate c1, ref Player c2)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < c1.model.Meshes.Count; i++)
    {
        // Check whether the bounding boxes of the two cubes intersect.
        BoundingSphere c1BoundingSphere = c1.model.Meshes[i].BoundingSphere;

        c1BoundingSphere.Center += c1.position + new Vector3(2, 0, 2);
        c1BoundingSphere.Radius = c1BoundingSphere.Radius / 1.5f;

        for (int j = 0; j < c2.model.Meshes.Count; j++)
        {
            BoundingSphere c2BoundingSphere = c2.model.Meshes[j].BoundingSphere;
            c2BoundingSphere.Center += c2.position;

            Vector3 dir=c2BoundingSphere.Center - c1BoundingSphere.Center;
            float center_dist_sq=dir.dot(dir);
            float min_dist=c2BoundingSphere.Radius+c1BoundingSphere.Radius;
            if (center_dist_sq < min_dist*min_dist) {
                    dir.normalize();
                    c2.position += dir*(min_dist-sqrt(center_dist_sq));
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Then your update can look more like:

```
for (int x = 0; x <= 29; x++) {
    for (int y = 0; y <= 29; y++) {
        if (crate[x, y].getType() == 11 && collisionEnabled) {
            CorrectCollisions(ref crate[x, y], ref player);
        }
    }
}
```

I'm not sure what the purpose of the (2,0,2) vector, or the 2/3rds thing is... I've just ignored them to express the concept

Comment: c2.position += (c2BoundingSphere.Center - c1BoundingSphere.Center)-(c2BoundingSphere.Radius - c1BoundingSphere.Radius); "Cannot covert Vector3 to float. Was the 2nd minus supposed to be a comma?

Comment: Whoops, sorry I should have thought of that. It's because I designed the idea in 1D. I've edited the example to show how to extract direction vector in 3D. I've also combined the sphere intersection since the math overlaps, there is no use doing it twice.

Comment: On this line :float center_dist_sq=dir.dot(dir); wouldn't you need two Vector3s for a DOT product?

Comment: @bbdude95 : Yeah, they are "dir" and "dir", notice the variable is called center distance squared. I originally wrote it as =dot(dir,dir) but realized that your framework looks object-oriented.

Comment: Yo I tried to implement something similar to this in JavaScript without any vector libraries, any idea how to resolve this by any chance? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61518457/javascript-wall-collision-on-convex-shapes-getting-stuck-at-corner