# JavaScript wall collision on convex shapes, getting stuck at corner

Tags: javascript, 2d, collision-detection, game-physics, collision

this is a follow up to this other question: [How do I handle player collision with corners of a wall](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/157267/how-do-i-handle-player-collision-with-corners-of-a-wall)

In inspiration of the code given in [its answer](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/160319/54454), I tried to write some new code.

Basically, in the original, the wall sliding works very well on the inside of the walls, but I wanted to make it work on the outside as well, so I made a new basic code engine, based on his technique:

```js
var aD =[]
var r
function start() {
 r = new CanvasRenderer(can),
  my = new scene();
 window.my = my
 eventHandler();
 my.add(new mesh({
  verts: [
   0,   0,
   100, 15,
   115, 60,
   50, 100,
   20, 75,2,8
  ],
  position: {
   x: 100,
   y:100
  },
  scale: {

   x:4,y:5
  },
  color:"orange",
  onupdate(me) {
  // me.position.x++
  }
 }));
 var g = false
 my.add(new mesh({
  primitive:"rect",
  name: "player",
  scale: {
   x: 50,
   y:50
  },
  position: {
   x: 311,
   y:75
  },
  origin: {
   x:0.5,
   y:0.5
  },
  onupdate(me) {
   var upKey = keys[38],
    downKey = keys[40],
    rightKey = keys[39],
    leftKey = keys[37],
    drx  = 0,
    dx = 0,
    speed = 5,
    turningSpeed = 3
   
   drx = leftKey ? -1 : rightKey ? 1 : 0
   forward = upKey ? 1 : downKey ? -1 : 0

   me.rotation.x += (
    (drx * Math.PI / 180 * turningSpeed )
   )
   me.rotation.y = 1;

   var xDir = Math.cos(me.rotation.x)
   var yDir = Math.sin(me.rotation.x)
   
   me.position.x += xDir  * forward * speed
   me.position.y += yDir * forward * speed

   for(var i = 0; i < my.objects.length; i++) {
    let cur = my.objects[i];
    if(cur.name !== me.name) {
     cur.lineSegments.forEach(l => {
      var col = checkCollision(
       me.position.x,
       me.position.y,
       me.scale.x/2,
       l
      )
      
      if(col) {
  
       me.position.y=col.y
       me.position.x = col.x
      }
      });
    }
   }


  
   
  }

 }));
 
 let i = setInterval(() => render(r, my), 16);
 r.on("resize", () => render(r, my));

}

function checkCollision(x1, y1, rad,l) {
  var dist = distance2(
       l.start[0],
       l.start[1],
       
       l.end[0],
       l.end[1]
      ),
       vec1 = [
        x1 - l.start[0],
        y1 - l.start[1]
       ],

       vec2 = [
        l.end[0] - l.start[0],
        l.end[1] - l.start[1]
       ],

       percentOfWall = (
        Math.max(
         0,
         Math.min(
          1, 
          dot(
           vec1[0],
           vec1[1],

           vec2[0],
           vec2[1]
          ) / dist
         )
        )
       ),
       projection = [
        l.start[0] + percentOfWall * vec2[0],
        l.start[1] + percentOfWall * vec2[1],
       ],
       acDist = Math.sqrt(distance2(
        x1, y1,
        projection[0], projection[1]
       ))
aD.push( () => {
      r.ctx.beginPath()
      r.ctx.fillStyle="green"
      r.ctx.arc(projection[0], projection[1], 5, 0, Math.PI*2);
      r.ctx.fill()
      r.ctx.closePath();
      })

     
     if(acDist < rad) {
      var mag = Math.sqrt(dist),
       delt = [
       l.end[0] - l.start[0],
       l.end[1] - l.start[1]
      ],
       normal = [
       delt[0] / mag,
       delt[1] / mag
      ]
      
      return {
      
       x: projection[0] + 

       rad * (normal[1] ),
      
        y:projection[1] + 
       rad* (-normal[0] ),
       projection,
       normal
      }
     }

     
}


function dot(x1, y1, x2, y2) {
 return (
  x1 * x2 + y1 * y2
 )
}

function distance2(x1, y1, x2, y2) {
 let dx = (x1 - x2), dy = (y1 - y2);
 return (
  dx * dx + dy * dy
 );
}

function render(r,s) {
//r.ctx.clearRect(0,0,r.ctx.canvas.width,r.ctx.canvas.height)
 s.update();
 r.render(s)
 aD.forEach(x=>x());
 aD = []
}

onload = start;

function eventHandler() {
 window.keys = {};
 addEventListener("keyup" , e=> {
  keys[e.keyCode] = false;
   
 });

 addEventListener("keydown" , e=> {
  keys[e.keyCode] = true;
 });
}

function CanvasRenderer(dom) {
 if(!dom) dom = document.createElement("canvas");
 
 var events = {}, self = this;
 function rsz() {
  dom.width = dom.clientWidth;
  dom.height = dom.clientHeight;
  self.dispatchEvent("resize");
 }
 
 window.addEventListener("resize", rsz); 

 let ctx = dom.getContext("2d");

 function render(scene) {
  ctx.clearRect(0,0,ctx.canvas.width,ctx.canvas.height);
  for(let i = 0; i < scene.objects.length; i++) {
   let o = scene.objects[i],
    verts = o.realVerts;

   
   ctx.beginPath();
   ctx.moveTo(
    verts[0] , 

    verts[1]
   );
   verts.forEach((v, i, ar) => {
    let y = i;
    


    ctx.lineTo(
     v[0] , 

     v[1]
    );
    
   });
   ctx.lineTo(
    verts[0],
    verts[1] 
   );
   ctx.fillStyle = o.color || "blue";
   ctx.lineWidth = 1;
   ctx.fill()
   ctx.stroke();
   ctx.closePath();
  }
 }

 Object.defineProperties(this, {
  domElement: {
   get: () => dom
  }, 
  ctx: {
   get: () => ctx
  },
  render: {
   get: () => render
  },
  on: {
   get: () => (nm, cb) => {
    if(!events[nm]) {
     events[nm] = [];
    }
    events[nm].push(data => {
     if(typeof cb == "function") {
      cb(data);
     }
    });
   }  
  },
  dispatchEvent: {
   get: () => (name, data) => {
    if(events[name]) {
     events[name].forEach(x => {
      x(data);
     });
    }
   }
  }
 });
 
 rsz();

}

function scene() {
 let objects = [];
 Object.defineProperties(this, {
  add: {
   get: () => obj => {
    objects.push(obj);
   }
  },
  objects: {
   get: () => objects
  },
  update: {
   get: () => () => {    
    objects.forEach(x => {
     if(typeof x.update == "function") {
      x.update();
     }
    });
    
   }
  }
 });
}

function mesh(data={}) {
 let verts = [],
  self = this,
  holder = {
   position:{},
   scale: {
    
   },
   rotation: {},
   origin:{}
  },
  actual = {
 
  },
  position = {},
  scale = {},
  rotation = {},
  origin = {},
  color,
  name,
  primitive,
  eventNames = "update",
  events = {},
  drawPrimitive = {
   circle(ctx) {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(
     self.position.x,
     self.position.y,
     5, 
     0,
     360 * Math.PI / 180
    );
    ctx.closePath();
   },
   rect(ctx) {
    ctx.strokeRect(
     self.position.x,
     self.position.y,
     30, 30
    );
   }
  },
  width = 1,
  height = 1,
  primitiveToVerts = {
   rect: () =>  [
     0, 0,
     width , 0,
     width, height,
     0, height
   ]
  },
  realVerts = verts,
  lineSegments = [],
  o = this;
 
 function updateRealVerts() {
   
   let  actualVerts = [],
    originedVerts = [],
    adjustedVerts = [],
    rotatedVerts = [],
    stepSize = o.step || 2,
    curVerts = [];
   
   o.verts.forEach((v, i) => {
    curVerts.push(v);
    if(
     (i - 1) % stepSize === 0 &&
     i !== 0
    ) {
     actualVerts.push(curVerts);
     curVerts = [];
    }
   });
   actualVerts = actualVerts.filter(x => x.length == stepSize);
   
   originedVerts = actualVerts.map(v => [
    v[0] - o.origin.x,
    v[1] - o.origin.y,
    v[2] - o.origin.z
   ]);
 
   rotatedVerts = originedVerts.map(v => 
    [

     v[0] * Math.cos(o.rotation.x) - 
     v[1] * Math.sin(o.rotation.x),

     v[0] * Math.sin(o.rotation.x) + 
     v[1] *Math.cos(o.rotation.x),
v[2]
    ]
   );

   adjustedVerts = rotatedVerts.map(v => 
    [
     v[0] * 
     o.scale.x + 
     o.position.x,
 
     v[1] * 
     o.scale.y + 
     o.position.y,

     v[2] * 
     o.scale.z + 
     o.position.z,
    ]
   );

   realVerts = adjustedVerts;
   updateLineSegments();
 } 

 function updateLineSegments() {
    let lines = [];
    for(let i = 0, a = realVerts; i < a.length;i++) {
     let start = [], end = []
     if(i < a.length - 1) {
      start = a[i];
      end = a[i + 1];
     } else {
      start = a[i];
      end = a[0];
     }

     lines.push({
      start, end
     })
    }
    lineSegments = lines;
 }
 Object.defineProperties(position, {
  x: {
   get: () => holder.position.x || 0,
   set: v => holder.position.x = v
  },
  y: {
   get: () => holder.position.y || 0,
   set: v => holder.position.y = v
  },
  z: {
   get: () => holder.position.z || 0,
   set: v => holder.position.z = v
  }
 });

 Object.defineProperties(scale, {
  x: {
   get: () => holder.scale.x || 1,
   set: v => holder.scale.x = v
  },
  y: {
   get: () => holder.scale.y || 1,
   set: v => holder.scale.y = v
  },
  z: {
   get: () => holder.scale.z || 1,
   set: v => holder.scale.z = v
  }
 });

 Object.defineProperties(rotation, {
  x: {
   get: () => holder.rotation.x || 0,
   set: v => holder.rotation.x = v
  },
  y: {
   get: () => holder.rotation.y || 0,
   set: v => holder.rotation.y = v
  },
  z: {
   get: () => holder.rotation.z || 0,
   set: v => holder.rotation.z = v
  }
 });

 Object.defineProperties(origin, {
  x: {
   get: () => holder.origin.x || 0,
   set: v => holder.origin.x = v
  },
  y: {
   get: () => holder.origin.y || 0,
   set: v => holder.origin.y = v
  },
  z: {
   get: () => holder.origin.z || 0,
   set: v => holder.origin.z = v
  }
 });
 

 Object.defineProperties(this, {
  verts: {
   get: ()=>verts,
   set(v) {
    verts = v
   }
  },
  name: {
   get: ()=>name,
   set(v) {
    name = v
   }
  },
  primitive: {
   get: ()=>primitive,
   set(v) {
    primitive = v;
    let newVerts = primitiveToVerts[v];
    if(newVerts) {
     this.verts = newVerts();
    }
   }
  },
  width: {
   get: ()=>width,
   set(v) {
    width = v
   }
  },
  height: {
   get: ()=>height,
   set(v) {
    height = v
   }
  },
  position: {
   get: () => position,
   set: v => {
    position.x = v.x || 0;
    position.y = v.y || 0;
    position.z = v.z || 0;
   }
  },
  scale: {
   get: () => scale,
   set: v => {
    scale.x = v.x || v.x === 0 ? v.x : 1;
    scale.y = v.y  || v.y === 0 ? v.y : 1;
    scale.z = v.z  || v.z === 0 ? v.z : 1;
   }
  },
  rotation: {
   get: () => rotation,
   set: v => {
    rotation.x = v.x || 0;
    rotation.y = v.y || 0;
    rotation.z = v.z || 0;
   }
  },
  origin: {
   get: () => origin,
   set: v => {
    origin.x = v.x || 0;
    origin.y = v.y || 0;
    origin.z = v.z || 0;
   }
  },
  color: {
   get: () => color,
   set: v => {
    color = v;
   }
  },
  realVerts: {
   get: () => realVerts
  },
  lineSegments: {
   get: () => lineSegments
  },
  update: {
   get: () => () => {
    if(events["update"]) {
     events.update.forEach(x => {
      updateRealVerts();
      x(this);
     });
    }
   }
  },
  on: {
   get: () => (nm, fnc) => {
    if(!events[nm]) events[nm] = [];
    events[nm].push(stuff => {
     if(typeof fnc == "function") {
      fnc(stuff);
     }
    });
   }
  }
 });

 eventNames.split(" ").forEach(x => {
  var name = "on" + x;
  if(!this.hasOwnProperty(name)) {
   Object.defineProperty(this, name, {
    get: () => events[name],
    set(v) {
     events[x] = [
      data => {
       typeof v == "function" && v(data)
      }
     ];
    }
   });
  }
 });

 for(let k in data) {
  this[k] = data[k]
 }

 updateRealVerts();

}
```

```css
canvas{
 width:100%;
 height:100%;
 position:absolute;
 top:0; 
 left:0px
}

.wow{
 float:right;
 z-index:1298737198
}
```

```html
<meta charset="utf-8">
<button onclick="start()" class=wow>ok</button>
<canvas id=can>

</canvas>
```

See line 71 for the collision detection implementation call (and the return value of the function there).

The problem is, as you can hopefully see (just fullscreen it and use arrow keys to move, try colliding with the orange mesh at the corners) that it slides fine, but when it gets to the corners, it gets stuck at them.

Any ideas how to fix this -- without using any kind of external libraries etc. (only what's available in the snippet)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say just check that you are not in the corner - discard cases when `percentOfWall` is either exactly `0` or exactly `1`

**EDIT**: to address the corners mentioned in the comments I have to explain why your implementation got stuck. It calculated penetration with all the walls and decreased position change by this penetration amount. In the corner, the object collided with both edges at once, and being repulsed from both at once stopped moving.

As you rightly noticed, in the corners your square gets inside the obstacle for one frame and then is pushed out on the consequent frame.

Alternative solutions, however, are more complicated and harder to debug, but here is a sketch for a couple of options:

- Limit the collisions to repulse from only one wall at a time and early exit your `forEach` loop. This is a simple solution which will work in this particular example but won't work in the general case, for example in the corner when you need to collide with 2 walls preventing you to go in both directions.
- Add a tiny circle in each of the corners and collide with it to avoid going inside. The normal is along the line between the center of the circle and the point of contact. That smooths the normal discontinuity you have in the corners and there is always a single normal along which the object is repulsed, continuously changing from one segment to the other.

Directing the "push" to outside each segment of the obstacle (which is what you are asking) wouldn't prevent stopping as on the corner (which is exactly the point you are concerned with), both walls will collide with your object and "outside" will be in the opposite directions. So it'll get stuck the same way as before and for exact same reason - normals will be not continuous.

I hope that helps

```js
var aD =[]
var r
function start() {
 r = new CanvasRenderer(can),
  my = new scene();
 window.my = my
 eventHandler();
 my.add(new mesh({
  verts: [
   0,   0,
   100, 15,
   115, 60,
   50, 100,
   20, 75,2,8
  ],
  position: {
   x: 100,
   y:100
  },
  scale: {

   x:4,y:5
  },
  color:"orange",
  onupdate(me) {
  // me.position.x++
  }
 }));
 var g = false
 my.add(new mesh({
  primitive:"rect",
  name: "player",
  scale: {
   x: 50,
   y:50
  },
  position: {
   x: 311,
   y:75
  },
  origin: {
   x:0.5,
   y:0.5
  },
  onupdate(me) {
   var upKey = keys[38],
    downKey = keys[40],
    rightKey = keys[39],
    leftKey = keys[37],
    drx  = 0,
    dx = 0,
    speed = 5,
    turningSpeed = 3
   
   drx = leftKey ? -1 : rightKey ? 1 : 0
   forward = upKey ? 1 : downKey ? -1 : 0

   me.rotation.x += (
    (drx * Math.PI / 180 * turningSpeed )
   )
   me.rotation.y = 1;

   var xDir = Math.cos(me.rotation.x)
   var yDir = Math.sin(me.rotation.x)
   
   me.position.x += xDir  * forward * speed
   me.position.y += yDir * forward * speed

   for(var i = 0; i < my.objects.length; i++) {
    let cur = my.objects[i];
    if(cur.name !== me.name) {
     cur.lineSegments.forEach(l => {
      var col = checkCollision(
       me.position.x,
       me.position.y,
       me.scale.x/2,
       l
      )
      
      if(col) {
       me.position.y=col.y
       me.position.x = col.x
      }
      });
    }
   }


  
   
  }

 }));
 
 let i = setInterval(() => render(r, my), 16);
 r.on("resize", () => render(r, my));

}

function checkCollision(x1, y1, rad,l) {
  var dist = distance2(
       l.start[0],
       l.start[1],
       
       l.end[0],
       l.end[1]
      ),
       vec1 = [
        x1 - l.start[0],
        y1 - l.start[1]
       ],

       vec2 = [
        l.end[0] - l.start[0],
        l.end[1] - l.start[1]
       ],

       percentOfWall = (
        Math.max(
         0,
         Math.min(
          1, 
          dot(
           vec1[0],
           vec1[1],

           vec2[0],
           vec2[1]
          ) / dist
         )
        )
       ),
       projection = [
        l.start[0] + percentOfWall * vec2[0],
        l.start[1] + percentOfWall * vec2[1],
       ],
       acDist = Math.sqrt(distance2(
        x1, y1,
        projection[0], projection[1]
       ))
aD.push( () => {
      r.ctx.beginPath()
      r.ctx.fillStyle="green"
      r.ctx.arc(projection[0], projection[1], 5, 0, Math.PI*2);
      r.ctx.fill()
      r.ctx.closePath();
      })

     
     if(acDist < rad && percentOfWall > 0 && percentOfWall < 1) {
      var mag = Math.sqrt(dist),
       delt = [
       l.end[0] - l.start[0],
       l.end[1] - l.start[1]
      ],
       normal = [
       delt[0] / mag,
       delt[1] / mag
      ]
      
      return {
      
       x: projection[0] + 

       rad * (normal[1] ),
      
        y:projection[1] + 
       rad* (-normal[0] ),
       projection,
       normal
      }
     }

     
}


function dot(x1, y1, x2, y2) {
 return (
  x1 * x2 + y1 * y2
 )
}

function distance2(x1, y1, x2, y2) {
 let dx = (x1 - x2), dy = (y1 - y2);
 return (
  dx * dx + dy * dy
 );
}

function render(r,s) {
//r.ctx.clearRect(0,0,r.ctx.canvas.width,r.ctx.canvas.height)
 s.update();
 r.render(s)
 aD.forEach(x=>x());
 aD = []
}

onload = start;

function eventHandler() {
 window.keys = {};
 addEventListener("keyup" , e=> {
  keys[e.keyCode] = false;
   
 });

 addEventListener("keydown" , e=> {
  keys[e.keyCode] = true;
 });
}

function CanvasRenderer(dom) {
 if(!dom) dom = document.createElement("canvas");
 
 var events = {}, self = this;
 function rsz() {
  dom.width = dom.clientWidth;
  dom.height = dom.clientHeight;
  self.dispatchEvent("resize");
 }
 
 window.addEventListener("resize", rsz); 

 let ctx = dom.getContext("2d");

 function render(scene) {
  ctx.clearRect(0,0,ctx.canvas.width,ctx.canvas.height);
  for(let i = 0; i < scene.objects.length; i++) {
   let o = scene.objects[i],
    verts = o.realVerts;

   
   ctx.beginPath();
   ctx.moveTo(
    verts[0] , 

    verts[1]
   );
   verts.forEach((v, i, ar) => {
    let y = i;
    


    ctx.lineTo(
     v[0] , 

     v[1]
    );
    
   });
   ctx.lineTo(
    verts[0],
    verts[1] 
   );
   ctx.fillStyle = o.color || "blue";
   ctx.lineWidth = 1;
   ctx.fill()
   ctx.stroke();
   ctx.closePath();
  }
 }

 Object.defineProperties(this, {
  domElement: {
   get: () => dom
  }, 
  ctx: {
   get: () => ctx
  },
  render: {
   get: () => render
  },
  on: {
   get: () => (nm, cb) => {
    if(!events[nm]) {
     events[nm] = [];
    }
    events[nm].push(data => {
     if(typeof cb == "function") {
      cb(data);
     }
    });
   }  
  },
  dispatchEvent: {
   get: () => (name, data) => {
    if(events[name]) {
     events[name].forEach(x => {
      x(data);
     });
    }
   }
  }
 });
 
 rsz();

}

function scene() {
 let objects = [];
 Object.defineProperties(this, {
  add: {
   get: () => obj => {
    objects.push(obj);
   }
  },
  objects: {
   get: () => objects
  },
  update: {
   get: () => () => {    
    objects.forEach(x => {
     if(typeof x.update == "function") {
      x.update();
     }
    });
    
   }
  }
 });
}

function mesh(data={}) {
 let verts = [],
  self = this,
  holder = {
   position:{},
   scale: {
    
   },
   rotation: {},
   origin:{}
  },
  actual = {
 
  },
  position = {},
  scale = {},
  rotation = {},
  origin = {},
  color,
  name,
  primitive,
  eventNames = "update",
  events = {},
  drawPrimitive = {
   circle(ctx) {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(
     self.position.x,
     self.position.y,
     5, 
     0,
     360 * Math.PI / 180
    );
    ctx.closePath();
   },
   rect(ctx) {
    ctx.strokeRect(
     self.position.x,
     self.position.y,
     30, 30
    );
   }
  },
  width = 1,
  height = 1,
  primitiveToVerts = {
   rect: () =>  [
     0, 0,
     width , 0,
     width, height,
     0, height
   ]
  },
  realVerts = verts,
  lineSegments = [],
  o = this;
 
 function updateRealVerts() {
   
   let  actualVerts = [],
    originedVerts = [],
    adjustedVerts = [],
    rotatedVerts = [],
    stepSize = o.step || 2,
    curVerts = [];
   
   o.verts.forEach((v, i) => {
    curVerts.push(v);
    if(
     (i - 1) % stepSize === 0 &&
     i !== 0
    ) {
     actualVerts.push(curVerts);
     curVerts = [];
    }
   });
   actualVerts = actualVerts.filter(x => x.length == stepSize);
   
   originedVerts = actualVerts.map(v => [
    v[0] - o.origin.x,
    v[1] - o.origin.y,
    v[2] - o.origin.z
   ]);
 
   rotatedVerts = originedVerts.map(v => 
    [

     v[0] * Math.cos(o.rotation.x) - 
     v[1] * Math.sin(o.rotation.x),

     v[0] * Math.sin(o.rotation.x) + 
     v[1] *Math.cos(o.rotation.x),
v[2]
    ]
   );

   adjustedVerts = rotatedVerts.map(v => 
    [
     v[0] * 
     o.scale.x + 
     o.position.x,
 
     v[1] * 
     o.scale.y + 
     o.position.y,

     v[2] * 
     o.scale.z + 
     o.position.z,
    ]
   );

   realVerts = adjustedVerts;
   updateLineSegments();
 } 

 function updateLineSegments() {
    let lines = [];
    for(let i = 0, a = realVerts; i < a.length;i++) {
     let start = [], end = []
     if(i < a.length - 1) {
      start = a[i];
      end = a[i + 1];
     } else {
      start = a[i];
      end = a[0];
     }

     lines.push({
      start, end
     })
    }
    lineSegments = lines;
 }
 Object.defineProperties(position, {
  x: {
   get: () => holder.position.x || 0,
   set: v => holder.position.x = v
  },
  y: {
   get: () => holder.position.y || 0,
   set: v => holder.position.y = v
  },
  z: {
   get: () => holder.position.z || 0,
   set: v => holder.position.z = v
  }
 });

 Object.defineProperties(scale, {
  x: {
   get: () => holder.scale.x || 1,
   set: v => holder.scale.x = v
  },
  y: {
   get: () => holder.scale.y || 1,
   set: v => holder.scale.y = v
  },
  z: {
   get: () => holder.scale.z || 1,
   set: v => holder.scale.z = v
  }
 });

 Object.defineProperties(rotation, {
  x: {
   get: () => holder.rotation.x || 0,
   set: v => holder.rotation.x = v
  },
  y: {
   get: () => holder.rotation.y || 0,
   set: v => holder.rotation.y = v
  },
  z: {
   get: () => holder.rotation.z || 0,
   set: v => holder.rotation.z = v
  }
 });

 Object.defineProperties(origin, {
  x: {
   get: () => holder.origin.x || 0,
   set: v => holder.origin.x = v
  },
  y: {
   get: () => holder.origin.y || 0,
   set: v => holder.origin.y = v
  },
  z: {
   get: () => holder.origin.z || 0,
   set: v => holder.origin.z = v
  }
 });
 

 Object.defineProperties(this, {
  verts: {
   get: ()=>verts,
   set(v) {
    verts = v
   }
  },
  name: {
   get: ()=>name,
   set(v) {
    name = v
   }
  },
  primitive: {
   get: ()=>primitive,
   set(v) {
    primitive = v;
    let newVerts = primitiveToVerts[v];
    if(newVerts) {
     this.verts = newVerts();
    }
   }
  },
  width: {
   get: ()=>width,
   set(v) {
    width = v
   }
  },
  height: {
   get: ()=>height,
   set(v) {
    height = v
   }
  },
  position: {
   get: () => position,
   set: v => {
    position.x = v.x || 0;
    position.y = v.y || 0;
    position.z = v.z || 0;
   }
  },
  scale: {
   get: () => scale,
   set: v => {
    scale.x = v.x || v.x === 0 ? v.x : 1;
    scale.y = v.y  || v.y === 0 ? v.y : 1;
    scale.z = v.z  || v.z === 0 ? v.z : 1;
   }
  },
  rotation: {
   get: () => rotation,
   set: v => {
    rotation.x = v.x || 0;
    rotation.y = v.y || 0;
    rotation.z = v.z || 0;
   }
  },
  origin: {
   get: () => origin,
   set: v => {
    origin.x = v.x || 0;
    origin.y = v.y || 0;
    origin.z = v.z || 0;
   }
  },
  color: {
   get: () => color,
   set: v => {
    color = v;
   }
  },
  realVerts: {
   get: () => realVerts
  },
  lineSegments: {
   get: () => lineSegments
  },
  update: {
   get: () => () => {
    if(events["update"]) {
     events.update.forEach(x => {
      updateRealVerts();
      x(this);
     });
    }
   }
  },
  on: {
   get: () => (nm, fnc) => {
    if(!events[nm]) events[nm] = [];
    events[nm].push(stuff => {
     if(typeof fnc == "function") {
      fnc(stuff);
     }
    });
   }
  }
 });

 eventNames.split(" ").forEach(x => {
  var name = "on" + x;
  if(!this.hasOwnProperty(name)) {
   Object.defineProperty(this, name, {
    get: () => events[name],
    set(v) {
     events[x] = [
      data => {
       typeof v == "function" && v(data)
      }
     ];
    }
   });
  }
 });

 for(let k in data) {
  this[k] = data[k]
 }

 updateRealVerts();

}
```

```css
canvas{
 width:100%;
 height:100%;
 position:absolute;
 top:0; 
 left:0px
}

.wow{
 float:right;
 z-index:1298737198
}
```

```html
<meta charset="utf-8">
<button onclick="start()" class=wow>ok</button>
<canvas id=can>

</canvas>
```

Comment: very clever and simple solution! Although there is just one problem left to deal with: It would appear the when colliding with the corners, since they are not being checked at all, the player actually goes into them a bit, before being pushed back from the edges. A possible fix would be to calculate the necessary pushback when hittnig the corners, but, as you suggested, in an *independent* calculation from the rest of the wall (in some kind of if statement that checks if percentOfWall is 0 or 100), I think what would make this a perfect answer is to briefly describe how to get the pushback

Comment: I think currently the pushback direction is along the normal of the wall being collided (perpendicular to it), but in the case of a corner, it needs to be along the perpendicular line extruding from the corner which maches both of the edges on either side, if that makes sense, I just don't know what formula there is to calculate that line

Comment: The formula you are asking about is the sign of dot(normal,v) between the wall-normal and object velocity (Dx,Dy). I added an explanation of why that wouldn't help with getting stuck though and suggested alternatives.

Comment: hi again hope ur well. i tried pushingout instead of setting the positions, and in regards to `Directing the "push" to outside each segment of the obstacle (which is what you are asking) wouldn't prevent stopping as on the corner (which is exactly the point you are concerned with), both walls will collide with your object and "outside" will be in the opposite directions`, if i push the player equally away from both, away from the corner to the point that its no longer colliding with any, i think it would work, but how do i calculate that?

Comment: cant attach a picture but imagine if a third line was connected to the two other endpoints of the lines found at the point of intersection, and a right angle line was drawn from the point of intersection to that third line, that's the direction i want to push back the character [in the other way]. in other words, i need to find the line perpendicular to a third line that would be formed at either extremes of the other segments [points opposite the point of intersection, at each], that intersects with the point of intersection of the inner ends of those segments, if that makes sense

Comment: Yo don't mean to keep filing up your inbox but just keeping you posted... Yeah you were right about backing up against the corner, I realize that now. Tried it and since the direction one continues to move is still different than the direction pushed back, it just continues in a loop of being pushed back and immediately going back to the same place(sometimes depending on the angle) . What I think needs to happen is that it needs to keep moving along the same line of movement it was moving before, when it had only one collision, until the entire width of the character has passed the corner